# Spearman Correlation for multiple variables

Tags: correlation, spearman-rho

I want to characterize the correlation of a set of variables with a target variable using Spearman correlation since I expect the relationship to be monotonic but not necessarily linear. Specifically, I want to test if one set of variables is more correlated with the target variable than another, and if adding a variable to an existing set improves the correlation. How can I do this using the per-pair Spearman correlation coefficients and p values? There is the [coefficient of multiple correlation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Coefficient_of_multiple_correlation), but it seems to assume linear function.

Comment: At a glance I would guess that you can just rank transform your data and compute the coefficient of multiple correlation on the ranks. This would preserve monotonic relationships between variables while 'forgetting' about linearity.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "a *set* of variables is *more correlated*". I believe what you mean is that using the set of variables, you can predict the outcome variable better...but in that case, you should create predictions from the set of variables, and check the correlation between the predictions and the target variable.

Comment: How would you do it if you were looking for an analogue of Pearson correlation?